# ORA-01012: not logged on While executing alter system flush shared_pool;

Tags: oracle10g

I want to flush shared pool because of error like

```
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 32 bytes of shared memory
```

So I want to flush shared pool using

```
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

Connected as sysdba using

```
hwflow08:flman800 > sqlplus "conn as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Jan 28 05:39:56 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Enter password: Connected.
```

While executing alter system command we faced ORA-01012

```
SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache;
alter system flush buffer_cache
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01012: not logged on
```

Can anyone please guide how can I flush the Shared Pool ? (I dont want to shutdown the DB)

Comment: As i didn't get any response I left with option to SHUTDOWN DB.
So after STARTUP , when i connected through SYSDBA and executed same query `alter system flush shared_pool;`
This time it works perfectlly fine.
So question remains as why ORACLE is not allowing flush shared pool when it is out of memory ?
What is efficient way to use **alter system flush shared_pool;**

Comment: It's too late to comment on this since you have resolved  your issue. But, you could have first killed on the current sessions and then try to flush shared_pool.

Comment: whether session kill will release some memory? If yes whether is sufficient to parse/run flush query ? According to me oracle doesn't allow to execute this query because oracle doesn't have enough memory to parse it , i may wrong. @LalitKumarB Your comment looks interesting and make sense.

Comment: What I mean is, the current sessions(if any) would consume the SGA, eliminating them would release the memory in the shared pool.

Comment: @LalitKumarB : Ya..i got it...will Definitely try if issue occurs again. Thanks for responce